# Sticky nav bar to bottom of browser window

Tags: jquery, css-position, nav, sticky

I am trying to create a nav bar that is positioned at the bottom of the browser window when loaded, but as you scroll down sticks to the top of the browser.

It is kind of working on this site http://thomas-rogers.co.uk/BleepBleeps2/index.html but I can't get the nav bar to be positioned on the bottom of the browser window i.e. it is sometimes not visible depending on screen size etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just can't get my head around this bit.

Currently I am using this code

```
            <header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="eight columns offset-by-eight" id="logo-box">
        <h1 class="logo">BleepBleeps</h1>
        <h2 class="subheader">A family of little friends<br>that make parenting easier</h2>
    <!-- MAILCHIMP SIGNUP -->
        <form action="http://bleepbleeps.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=e6067eec57&amp;id=7e02f5f7e4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email" class="required email mc-field-group" id="mce-EMAIL">
            <input type="submit" value="Go" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="tooltip my-custom-theme" title="Sign up to receive amazing Bleep Bleeps content!">

            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
        </form><!-- end MAILCHIMP SIGNUP -->
    </div><!-- end logo-box -->
</div><!-- end container -->

<div class="hero">
    <img class="hero-image" src="images/bb-background2.png" alt="#">
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/bb_note.gif" alt="bleepbleeps icon" class="notes">
            <ul class="socialnav">
                <li class="circle-social tw"><a href="http://twitter.com/BleepBleeps"></a></li>
                <li class="circle-social fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/BleepBleeps"></a></li>
                <li class="circle-social tu"><a href="http://bleepbleeps.tumblr.com"></a></li>
                <li class="circle-social in"><a href="http://instagram.com/bleepbleeps"></a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
             nav {
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
height: 3em;
     }

    nav.navigation {
position: absolute;
padding-top: 1em;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.8;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 99;
     }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
nav.navigation {
    position: relative !important;
}
     }

    .sticky {
position: fixed !important;
top: 0;
     }

    .sticky2 {
position: fixed !important;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 10px;
top: 11px;
     }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.sticky {
position: relative; !important;
     }

.sticky2 {
    display: none !important;
}
     }

    .notes {
float:left;
margin-left: 10px;
     }

     var delay = (function(){
var timer = 0;
return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
         };
     })();

     $(function() {

         var pause = 100; // will only process code within delay(function() { ... }) every 100ms.

$(window).resize(function() {

    delay(function() {

        var width = $(window).width();

        $(document).ready(function() {  
            var stickyNavTop = $('.navigation').offset().top;  

            var stickyNav = function(){  
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

            if  (scrollTop > stickyNavTop + 5) {   
                $('.navigation').addClass('sticky');  
            } else {  
                $('.navigation').removeClass('sticky');   
            }  
            };


            stickyNav();  

            $(window).scroll(function() {  
                stickyNav();  
            });  
            }); 

             }, pause );

         });

         $(window).resize();

     });


     $(document).ready(function() {  
     var stickyNavTop2 = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').offset().top;  

     var stickyNav2 = function(){  
     var scrollTop2 = $(window).scrollTop();  

     if (scrollTop2 > stickyNavTop2) {   
         $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').addClass('sticky2');  
     } else {  
         $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').removeClass('sticky2');   
     }  
     };  

     stickyNav2();  

     $(window).scroll(function() {  
         stickyNav2();  
     });  
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do it.

Something like...

`$('.navigation').css('top',$(window).height()-50);`

You might want to subtract some pixels like the 50 so that it moves it up into the view of the user.

Comment: Hi @rjg132234, I'm completely new to using jQuery, so I'm not sure where I should put this. I entered it into my main.js file, but it didn't seem to position the nav at the bottom of the screen. Are you able to give me any more advice? Really appreciate the help! Thanks

Comment: My mistake, I think I misread your question. What is your exact problem? The site you provided does have a navigation bar at the bottom of the page (although the main image is so big it is below that) and then when you scroll it sticks to the top. 

Can you better describe what your problem is?

Comment: Hi @rjg132234, thanks for getting back to me. I wanted the nav bar to be fixed to the bottom of the browser window, on all devices when the page is initially loaded. As you have said, maybe it is just a case of changing the image size? Is there another way around this?

Comment: Based on what you told me, sounds like your options are to either 

1) Leave the navigation bar where it is and shrink the height of the main image so you see the nav bar on load up or 

2) Use CSS to move the bar up initially so it shows up onload. Either by adding bottom:166px to nav.navigation {} css or you use jQuery and do something like: 

$('.navigation').css('bottom', $(window).height()-100);

This would set the navigation 100 pixels up from the height of the browser the site is opened in. You can probably play around with the number of pixels you want.

Comment: Thanks @rjg132234! That helped massively :) Really appreciate the time you took to help out!